# Bootstrap 4 align label below radio button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know I can make radio button below label like this

```css
.radioGroupBelow label{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0.2em;
}
.radioGroupBelow label input[type="radio"] {
    display:block;
    margin:0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioGroupBelow">
    Fruits:

    <label for="fruit1"> Orange
        <input type="radio" name="fruits" id="fruit1">
    </label>

    <label for="fruit2">Apple
        <input type="radio" name="fruits" id="fruit2">
    </label>

    <label for="fruit3">Grape
        <input type="radio" name="fruits" id="fruit3">
    </label>

    <label for="fruit4">Lemon
        <input type="radio" name="fruits" id="fruit4">
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/uHjpa/

But I need to put label below radio buttons?

Answer (score -1):

With your code you can simply move the labels after the checkbox for the desired effect. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/465mwkfp/)

```
<label for="fruit1"> 
    <input type="radio" name="fruits" id="fruit1">
    Orange
</label>
```

Comment: Updated with jsfiddle